# Detect if there is Microsoft Access installed on the computer and the version of Microsoft Access c#

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have been requested by customer to make a Point of Sales system and I have been using local database (Microsoft Access 2010).

So, I have been thinking out this question: **How do the application detect if there is a Microsoft Access installed on the computer and which version?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way (bitness needs to match):

```
Type Access = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Access.Application");
if (Access != null)
{
    dynamic access = Activator.CreateInstance(Access);
    string ver = access.Version;
}
```

Comment: I like how this QA has a better answer than the duplicate question that was asked before.

Answer (score 5):

If I remember correctly, you don't really need to have Access installed on your system if all you want is to access the database file mdb/accdb from C#.  All you need to have is an ODBC or OLEDB driver; free for download from Microsoft.  I think that the latest versions of Windows already have them installed but I'm not sure and I cannot verify as all of my systems have Access installed on them.

However, if you want to use this as the base for Point of Sale system, this would not be a good idea as Access is way too unsecure, prone to corruption and without any integrated backup mecanism.  For something as important as a POS, using SQL-Server should be considered the minimum.

Comment: +1 for suggesting not to use Access for POS. I'd like to add that even SQL Server LocalDB is better than Access and considering that SQL Server Express is free, better switch to something as robust as that than suffer the consequences later.

Comment: Thank you guys, I will consider to use SQL instead in the next project. +1

Comment: That is correct. Access does not need to be installed for another application to utilize an Access database file. When the C# installation package is built, it should include any needed references.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over keys using the [RegistryKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office");

foreach (String keyName in key.GetSubKeyNames())
.....
```